# how to deploy webapp to iis10?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

i followed this tutorial: http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2016/09/aspnet-web-api-and-sql-server.html. It works fine, but now i want to deploy it to iis. i followed the instructions here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/ and instead of using port 80 i used port 8080. but when i browse/view the webapp it gives the following error:

Service Unavailable. HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

what could be the problem?

here's my startup.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication10.Startup))]

namespace WebApplication10
{
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: open Run(start+R) and type "eventvwr". Then see the application logs. You will be able to see the exact reason

Comment: when u build web api u need know root path or make root at where can modify (like web config). could u post your code at startup.cs and URL link u type ?

Comment: Did you check the app pool setting in IIS? Are trying to deploy on the same dev machine or a different server?

Comment: @Vasanth i'm trying to deploy on the same dev machine. what should be the app pool setting? i used .net 4.5

Answer (score 0):

Below are the steps you would Follow :

**STEP 1:**

Make sure that you enable `IIS(10)` . follow these steps https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181052(v=vs.80).aspx

**STEP 2:**

Search for IIS , then an IIS  Manager, a  window will open

**STEP 3:**

On the right panel , you will see your PC Name , then press a dropdown , you will see **Sites**.

**STEP 4:**

Right click on **Sites** , and click on **Add Website**.

**STEP 5:**

Add Website Window will Open then , type in any **Site Name** of your choice ,
in the **physical path** , trace the folder of your website , then on **Port** field assign any port number `like 8050` , *but make sure that there's no website using that port number* , then leave **Hostname** blank and press ok

**STEP 6 :**

Your site will be listed under **Sites** , left click on it , then on the **Left panel**  you will see **Browse Website** , click on **Browse*:8050 (http)**

***Then it will work like charm.***

Hope it helped you.